# Where/Filter from Table object using a Dictionary (or **kwargs)

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I'm trying to update all Users in the users Table given some criteria.

```
update = ({"username" : "user1"}, {"address" : "1234", "password" : "newpass"})
users = Table(...)
```

I'm trying queries like:

```
users.update().where(**update[0]).values(update[1])
users.select().filter_by(**update[0]).update(update[1])
```

With a session, I know I could do:

```
session.query(Users).filter_by(**update[0])
```

Is there an analogue for a table object?

Answer (score 9):

you can create where clauses list and pass it to `where()`

```
from sqlalchemy import and_

update = ({"username" : "user1"}, {"address" : "1234", "password" : "newpass"})

where_clauses = [users.c[key]==value for (key, value) in update[0].items()]
users.update().where(and_(*where_clauses)).values(**update[1])
```

Comment: I wonder if it's already time to update `iteritems()` to just `items()` :)